# smartphones in fligth mode when bad weather conditions?

Tags: emergency, emergency-procedures

when flying form Vienna to Stuttgart, we had a terrible weather conditions, before landing the cabin crew announced that by request of the captain, all electronic devices must be switch off, not allowing even their use in flight mode..

any particular reason for that??
maybe avoiding the selfie effect by millenials if something goes wrong by landing??

thanks is advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "terrible weather conditions"? Turbulence, strong winds or thunderstorms? Or low visibility, which might have required a CAT II or III ILS autoland? Also, which aircraft were you flying in?

Comment: Related: [Instrument landing: why do all electronic devices need to be shut off?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11555/instrument-landing-why-do-all-electronic-devices-need-to-be-shut-off)

Comment: it was pretty windy up in the air and when landing it was  very foggy..

Comment: it would be better if you would tell us the flight number and day of flight. "pretty windy" does not help much in understanding the conditions

Comment: EW 2757, yesterday 8:55 pm